# Uitableview Accessorytype Checkmark Reset Code

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I know how to handle with cellaccesory type check mark, here I want a button to Uncheck the entire tablecell which are checkmarked? Here my code, can any one please help me to code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
UIBarButtonItem *rest = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle: @"RESET" style:      UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(uncheckCells)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rest,flexibleSpace,flexibleSpace,home,nil]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here the code for my functions

```
-(void)uncheckCells//unchecking function
{
[self.tableView reloadData];//HERE WHAT SHOULD I DO
}
-(void)hom
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
cell.textLabel.text = [ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
if(cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
cell.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xd05818);
cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"packed";
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
}
else
{
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=@""; 
}
return cell;
[self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
(void) deselect
{   
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]      animated:YES];

}
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
[tableView reloadData];    
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
printf("User selected row %d\n", [indexPath row] + 1);
if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] ==      UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
else
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [self performSelector:@selector(deselect) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code, how are you implementing this?

Comment: Saw your edit, please check my answer below. It will work for you.

Comment: i add code in question...please check

Comment: Where is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: add this `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` in your `if (cell == nil)` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing checkmarks on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. A `reloadData` will work for you.

For eg.

Say you have a button with selector `uncheckCells`

```
-(void)uncheckCells
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This should work you.

EDIT: add `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` in your `if (cell == nil)` condition.

Or do this:

```
-(void)uncheckCells
{
for (int section = 0, sectionCount = self.tableView.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (int row = 0, rowCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: @digidreamz I have added a comment above in your question, please check it. I'm also editing my answer.

Comment: This is impossible, and yes, don't do `reloadData` inside you `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: The trouble with this code is that you are changing the display of of the check mark. This sort of change belongs at the datasource level.

Comment: @Abizern, you can see that we tried it first at datasource level.

Comment: @OhhMee My opinion is that you should have tried to make the datasource level changes work rather than hack around it by manipulating the tableview directly. It probably didn't work because the checkmark is being set on the tableview's cells directly rather than on the datasource.

Answer (score -1):

From reading your code, it looks like you are setting the checkmark on the table view itself.

What you should really be doing is storing whether or not a cell has a check mark in your data source, and using this information in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to display a checkmark or not.

And your deselect method should be going through you datasource and unsetting whatever marker you have there that says whether or not your tableview has a check mark.

That way, when you scroll a tableview, or just call `[tableView reloadData];` your datastore will be used to decide whether or not to display a checkmark or not.